# Encoding array of bytes from string (Polish fonts)

Tags: c#, string, encoding

I can't handle with encoding in my language (Poland).
When I write `żółw` it works like a charm, but when I write `ślimak` there isn't `ś` in my array.

I tried also with `UTF-8`, but with no results.
Here is encoding in 1250. Works with `ż,ó,ł`, not with `ą,ź...`.

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250).GetBytes(postdata);
```

Above code is used to communicate with web server, so I think the problem is before communication.

---

Tried also:

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding(28592).GetBytes(postdata); //iso-8859-2 Central European (ISO)
```

Solved, `iso-8859-2 Central European (ISO)` was the correct answer. (I was running old exe project file).

Comment: Utf-16, also tried :) iso-8859-2 was the right solution

Comment: If you find the answer your self post it as an answer and accept it.  That enable people vote your answer and closes the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding(28592).GetBytes(postdata); //iso-8859-2 Central European (ISO)
```

Solved, `iso-8859-2 Central European (ISO)` was the correct answer. (I was running old exe project file).

Answer (score 2):

You should not expect there to be a `ś` in the array; it needs to be encoded, and the encoded value is differerent. I would advise using UTF-8 here in which case you should expect 0xC5 0x9B in the output, as that is the UTF-8 encoding of `ś`.

If you use 28592, then 0xB6 is the encoded form, and round-trips successfully.

Comment: I am working on ENG version windows, and I had problem with polish diacratic fonts. The solution was to use `8859-2` because I need it to send that encoded string to server. But thanks for an answer :)

Comment: @Lumma then it depends entirely on what encoding that server expects to use. There is no single right answer, except "the one it expects" (which is not in the question)